# Ubuntu not showing apps and normal login screen why?

Tags: server

I am starting ubuntu from virtual machine and when its open it is not showing normal screen for user login , It showing black screen to login and after that its not opening apps and other things screen ,anyone please help how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

[Ubuntu Screen I mage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZENf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged with "server". So there may be the reason of Ubuntu not showing apps and normal login screen: a server installation does not install a graphical user desktop by default. A server commonly is administered through the console.

You can install a desktop environment on top of an Ubuntu server installation, though.